# rtrim function cuts to many characters

Tags: php

Why:

```
$string = 'foofoxoa';
$toCut = 'xoa';
rtrim($string, $toCut);
```

return me:

> foof

instead of:

> foofo

? I don't want to use str_replace or substr for this, because $string and $cut can have different values.

In addition, $cut can be twice in $string, and I want to cut only from the end.

Comment: `rtrim` takes a list of characters to cut in string format. It's not treated as a string. If you change it to `oxa` or `axo` it will still behave the same - cut any of those characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because o is in the list of characters to remove from the end.
I think rtrim works its way from end to start and once it reaches a character not in the list it stops.

Example:

```
php > $string = 'foofolxoa';
php > $toCut = 'xoa';
php > echo rtrim($string, $toCut);
foofol
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php#35108